# Problematic DateTime Comparison SQL Query Not Working

Tags: php, sql, date, datetime, odbc

I have a problem with executing ODBC query. I am trying to achieve something simple.

```
SELECT t.* FROM table t WHERE DateTime > '#2014-05-05 00:00:00#'
```

I have tried to execute with or without hashes (#) and quotes around the datetime, but no success with that. Also, instead of using >, < and other comparison operators I have tried to use `BETWEEN`.

In addition several formats "dd/mm/yyyy", "mm/dd/yyyy", "dd.mm.yyyy", etc. plus standard sql format (iso) were tested and the result is the same.

The approach looks like:

```
$sql = "SELECT t.* FROM table t WHERE DateTime > '#...#'";
$result = odbc_fetch_array(odbc_exec($odbc_connection, $sql));
```

After this execution I receive some 5-10 symbol binary error, but no error message (with odb_error and odbc_errormsg), in addition to the:

**No tuples available at this result index**

(The topic: ODBC error in PHP: “No tuples available at this result index” is not helping)

Could it be some ODBC issue (old version etc.) or we should cast another black magic through `odbc_exec`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe ODBC have trouble with reserved word datetime.
I don't know how to escape quotes in PHP, try

```
SELECT t.* FROM table t WHERE t."DateTime" > '20140505'";
```

Comment: If I specify the where like this I receive all results.

Comment: @LachezarTodorov where is the problem now? do you skip ODBC error?

Comment: It seams that the problem is in the odbc driver. It does not accept anything that should work in where clause.  
I just changed the way I'm reading the data and stoped using the were clause. It's not the best way, but it's my only option now.

Answer (score 1):

You should use ODBC syntax for datetimes which is `{ ts '1998-05-02 01:23:56.123' }`. You can omit the partial seconds. See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190234%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the TO_DATE() function? You can specify the format you are using.

```
SELECT t.* FROM table t WHERE DateTime > TO_DATE('2014-05-05 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```